# Linking new iPad XIBs to old classes?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, class, interface

I am beginning to convert my app to iPhone/iPad supported. **I can't figure out how to link my new iPad XIB files to my old classes.** Maybe someone has some helpful info they could share!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite getting what exactly you mean.. but changing xib class is straight forward.. see screenshot.. 
if you click on drop down next to CLASS it should show all the UIViewControllers in you project.[image]

Comment: I go: File > New File... > Application XIB > Product > iPad. But I don't see my classes in that drop-down box.

Comment: Make sure you selecting files owner on the Window.